# searching for keywords in a file using python

Tags: python, search, pdf

how can i search for "/Count 1" , and print the number follows /Count. here it is 1
and this is a part of a file structure

```
 <</Type/Pages/Kids[4 0 R]/Count 1>>endobj
```

I wrote this code but in this case it prints 0 instead of 1:

```
data = file(f,"rb")
rxcountpages = re.compile("/Count \d*", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
x = rxcountpages.search(data.read())
print x.group()
```

where is the problem

Comment: Try putting `\d*` in a capture group and using `findall` instead of `search`.

Comment: please could you show me how because I'm new in using python

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = "<</Type/Pages/Kids[4 0 R]/Count 1>>endobj/Count 5"

print re.findall("(Count \d+)",s) # Count followed by  1 or more digits
['Count 1', 'Count 5']
```

Comment: I want to print ===> Count  1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try open file in other mode

```
data = file(f,"r")
```

(without `b`)

And also to get just number you should use this regexp:

```
/Count (\d*)
```

and then print

```
x.group(1)
```

All together it will look like this:

```
data = file(f,"r")
rxcountpages = re.compile("/Count \d*", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
x = rxcountpages.search(data.read())
print x.group(1)
```